# How I can have a Service provider to my All widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

I made an Api class:

```
class Api
{
   // Token for authentication
   String bearerToken;

   // Generate a bearer token
   void login(String username,String password){
     // Some Implementation hidden for simplicity
   }

   void refreshToken(){
     // Some Implementation hidden for simplicity
   }

   void consumeAnEndpointUsingBearerToken(){
     // Some Implementation hidden for simplicity
   }
}
```

And I made a Login widget:

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final Api api;
  const LoginPage({Key? key, required this.title, required this.api})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState(api);
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String username = '';
  String password = '';
  final Api api;
  
  _LoginPageState(this.api)

  void __setUsername(username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  void __setPassword(password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  void _login() {
    setState(() {
       api.login(username,password);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AppTextInput(
              hintText: 'Username',
              onChanged: __setUsername,
            ),
            AppTextInput(
              obscureText: true,
              hintText: 'Password',
              onChanged: __setPassword,
            ),
            AppButton(
              onPressed: _login,
              text: 'Login',
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And an another page where api is Consumed:

```
class ConsumeApi extends StatelessWidget {
    const ConsumeApi({Key? key, required this.title, required this.api})
      : super(key: key);

   // Dender another PAge
}
```

So at every time I need to perform a login Ι''ll need to offer a common Api instance and pass it around. Is there a better way to have a common Api service and use a some sort of service provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Get_It for dependency injection.

Create injectionContainer file:

```
final sl = GetIt.instance;

void init(){
   sl.registerSingleton(() => Api());
}
```

in your main, you need to call init():

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  di.init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

and don't forget to Import the injectionContainer file:

```
import 'injection_container.dart' as di;
```

and now In every widget you can do this:

```
sl<Api>().login();
```

Now you have an object of API created for you when the app starts.

Comment: how can you unit test that widget then ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use service locator for this.
You can use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) which is widely used for this but you'll need to pass context for it.
If you do not want to pass context you can use [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it)

I am personally using [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) in my project and it's workking fine.