# How I can mock - replace a service in Dart?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73232440/4706711) I made a Dependency Injection container:

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:myapp/functional/api.dart';
import 'package:myapp/functional/userSettings.dart';

// Depedency Injection Container
final sl = GetIt.instance;

void initDepedencyInjection() {
  sl.registerSingleton<Api>(Api());
  sl.registerSingleton<UserSettings>(UserSettings());
}
```

The `functional/api.dart` contains the class:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class Api
{
  final String __base_url="https://example.com";
  final UserSettings settings = sl<UserSettings>();

  Furure<bool> login(String username, String password) async {
     final Uri url = Uri.parse(__base_url + "/token");
     var response = await http.post(url, body: {'username':username,'password':password});
     var responseJson = json.decode(response.body) as Map;
     await settings.saveSetting('token',responseJson['token']);
     return response.statusCode == 201;
  } 
}
```

Whereas my `functional/UserSettings.dart` contains the class:

```
import 'package:file/file.dart';
import 'package:file/local.dart';
import 'package:file/memory.dart';


class UserSettings
{
   late final FileSystem _fs;

   UserSettings(): _fs = LocalFileSystem();
   UserSettings.usingMemory(){
      _fs = MemoryFileSystem();
   }
   
   Future<void> saveSetting(String key, String value) async {
       // Some implementation Here.
   }
}
```

During testing I want to replace the way that I construct the `UserSettings` using the `usingMemory`. Do you know how I can do it?

There may be cases where I also may need to provide mocked services as well to the service container. It there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstanced you'll need instead of calling the `initDepedencyInjection` from the dependenct Injection container you'll need to set it up per test for example:

```dart
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:myapp/functional/injectionContainer.dart';
import 'package:myapp/functional/userSettings.dart';
import 'package:myapp/functional/api.dart';


void main() {
  test('Test api', () async {
      UserSettings settingsManager = UserSettings.usingMemory();
      sl.registerSingleton<UserSettings>(u);
      
      Api api = Api();
   
      // Futher Mocks etc etc
      // DO the actual test

      sl.unregister<UserSettings>();
  });
}
```

As you can see me manually register the instance we want and then before test closes we deregister it. It is essential to do it because if needed on other test we cannot re-register it.