# How I can re-register my service to service container in my tests?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I made the following tests:

```dart
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:myapp/functional/injectionContainer.dart';
import 'package:myapp/functional/userSettings.dart';
import 'package:myapp/functional/api.dart';


void main() {
  test('Test api', () async {
      UserSettings settingsManager = UserSettings.usingMemory();
      sl.registerSingleton<UserSettings>(u);
      
      Api api = Api();
   
      // Futher Mocks etc etc


  });
  test('Test api 2', () async {
      UserSettings settingsManager = UserSettings.usingMemory();
      sl.registerSingleton<UserSettings>(u);
      
      Api api = Api();
   
      // Futher Mocks etc etc


  });
}
```

But once I rent the second test I get the error:

> Invalid argument(s): Object/factory with  type UserSettings is already registered inside GetIt.

How I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73291306/4706711) you'll need to de-register the service from service container:

```dart
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:myapp/functional/injectionContainer.dart';
import 'package:myapp/functional/userSettings.dart';
import 'package:myapp/functional/api.dart';


void main() {
  test('Test api', () async {
      UserSettings settingsManager = UserSettings.usingMemory();
      sl.registerSingleton<UserSettings>(u);
      
      Api api = Api();
   
      // Futher Mocks etc etc

      sl.unregister<UserSettings>();
  });

  test('Test api 2', () async {
      UserSettings settingsManager = UserSettings.usingMemory();
      sl.registerSingleton<UserSettings>(u);
      
      Api api = Api();
   
      // Futher Mocks etc etc

      sl.unregister<UserSettings>();
  });
}
```

because the service at the service container is registered as singleton cannot be re-registered. So we need to clean-up our tests and de-register our mocked of faked services we did. (Using memory filesystem actually you want to mock the filesystem itself).